# AJAX model return data with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter.

I need to call JavaScript function on returned data through model in CodeIgniter .

View:

```
<SELECT name="crs" onchange='load_data_ajax(this)'>
    <OPTION value='1'>option 1</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='2'>option 2</OPTION>
</SELECT>
<div id="container"></div>
```

function:

```
function load_data_ajax(type){
    $.ajax({
        'url' : 'http://myproper.url',
        'type' : 'POST',
        'data' : {'type' : type.value},
        'success' : function(data){ 
            var container = $('#container');
            if(data){
                eval(container.html(data));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

myproper url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/js/tablefilter.js" id="t1"></script> 

<table id='table1' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <thead><tr>
        <th align='left'>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>huzefa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>husain</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" id="t2">
//<![CDATA[ 
    var props = {
        //enable_default_theme: true,
        filters_row_index: 1,
        headers_row_index: 1,
        //remember_grid_values: true,
        remember_page_number: true,
        alternate_rows: true,
        rows_counter: true,
        btn_reset: true,
        btn_reset_text: "Clear",
        loader: true,
        status_bar: true,
        loader: true,
        col_4: "checklist",
        col_3: "checklist",
        display_all_text: "All",
        col_width: ["50px","200px","200px","75px","50px"],
        selectable: true,
        editable: true,
        enable_default_theme: true,  

        ezEditTable_config: {
            default_selection: 'both'
        },


        //Grid layout properties
         sort_config: { sort_types: ['none','string','string','string','string'] },  
     grid_layout: true, grid_width: '700px', grid_height: '800px',  
    grid_enable_cols_resizer: true,  
    mark_active_columns: true, 
        //grid_width: '900px',
        on_filters_loaded: function(o){
                var headersRow = o.headTbl.rows[o.GetHeadersRowIndex()];
                var c = headersRow.cells[0];
                var ezConfig = o.fObj.ezEditTable_config;
                //header checkbox is referenced on ezEditTable configuration object o.ezEditTable.checkBoxAll
                ezConfig.checkBoxAll = tf_Tag(c, 'input')[0];
                //header checkbox always unselected at start
                ezConfig.checkBoxAll.checked = false;
                //Click event is attached to header checkbox, note o.fObj = TF configuration object
                tf_AddEvent(ezConfig.checkBoxAll, 'click', function(e){ o.fObj.toggleAll(o); tf_StopEvent(e); });
            },
            //col_width: ["170px","200px"],
            selectable: true,
            editable: false,
            ezEditTable_config: {
                key_navigation: false,
                key_selection: false,
                selection_model: 'multiple',
                default_selection: 'row',
                selected_row_css: 'ezSlcRow',

                on_after_selected_row: function(o, row){
                    var c = row.cells[0];
                    var checkBox = o.Tag(c, 'input')[0];
                    if(checkBox) checkBox.checked = true;
                },
                on_after_deselected_row: function(o, row){
                    var c = row.cells[0];
                    var checkBox = o.Tag(c, 'input')[0];
                    if(checkBox) checkBox.checked = false;
                    o.config.checkBoxAll.checked = false;
                }
            },
            //Custom select all function used by header checkbox
            toggleAll: function(tf){ //tf = parent object: TF
                var o = tf.ezEditTable; //ezEditTable object referenced inside TF object
                if(o.config.checkBoxAll.checked == false){
                    o.Selection.ClearSelections();
                } else {
                    for(var i=o.startRow; i<o.GetRowsNb(); i++){
                        //If table filtered, only valid rows are selected
                        if(tf.GetValidRowsIndex()==null || tf.GetValidRowsIndex().indexOf(i) != -1)
                            o.Selection.SelectRowByIndex(i);
                    }
                }
            },
        /*** Extensions manager ***/

    grid_enable_cols_resizer: false,  
    mark_active_columns: true,  
        //btn_showHide_cols_text: 'Columns&#9660;'
    }
    //var tf = setFilterGrid("demo",props);

//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" id="t3">
    var tf = setFilterGrid('table1', props);
</script>
```

The data is returned properly but JavaScript effects do not show.

When I tested without the model by directly putting the code and JavaScript in the main view file it shows properly with JavaScript effects.

Comment: javascript should be include before call ajax and then return only html from ajax. javascript did not load on run time and hence it should be  loading on execution of your current url.

Comment: no its not working with $('#container').html(data); too

Comment: What is `eval` doing there?

Comment: "The data is returned properly" — How are you testing this?

Comment: "but JavaScript effects do not show" — What do you mean by "effects"? The code should put the returned HTML in the container. Is that what you mean isn't happening? Or were you expecting some kind of transition to fire as well?